# How to fit HTML canvas to screen while maintaining aspect ratio and not cutting off the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm making a game using HTML canvas and javascript. My canvas is 1280 x 720 px (16:9 ratio). I want my game to be displayed at full screen, showing black bars if the screen ratio is not 16:9.

If I do this:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then my game is played at fullscreen, but stretched to fill screen if the screen ratio is not 16:9. I don't want it to be stretched, I want to show black bars if needed.

If I do this:

```
canvas {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then the canvas keeps the right aspect ratio, but it will be cut off if the screen is wider than 16:9, and I don't want that either.

How can I achieve this? Other answers I found revolve around updating canvas.width and canvas.height on window resize, but I'd rather not resize canvas.width or canvas.height since the game is designed to work under 1280 x 720. Sure I could scale the drawing according to canvas.width and canvas.height, but I wonder if this can be achieved without doing that.

Thank you

Comment: canvas is a `replaced-level element`. As such `object-fit` can be applied to it. Particular you looking into `object-fit: contain;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First as stated in the comments already, canvas is a `replaced-level element`. As such `object-fit` can be applied to it just like with images that are used for this demonstration.

The solution starts with a "wrapper" (`div.fullscreen`). This element is positioned to fill the entire viewport by using: `position: fixed; inset: 0;` (`inset: 0;` = `top, right, bottom, left: 0` not fully supported yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset).

Next we address the image within this wrapper (or the canvas in your case)  and setting the `max-height` and `max-width` to `100%`. Then we use `object-fit: contain;` to let the canvas maintain its aspect-ratio but filling the wrapper without getting cut off.

Last but not least we use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to display the canvas in the vertical and horizontal center.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fullscreen img {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know about the object-fit property, it worked just like I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: Beware though, calculating mouse position relative to the canvas content becomes tedious when you change the object-fit, not really a great advice for games, where calculating yourself the correct image dimension will also allow to not render bigger than displayed (better perfs).